# Is there a way to Log in or Sign up with instagram in flutter?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, instagram, data-mining

I'm sorry, I'm still a beginner in programming. I've tried looking into firebase, but it does not work with instagram. I'm planning to use the user's instagram information such as followers, etc. That's the reason why I need the log in/sign up with instagram in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

There's a sample code on github [here](https://github.com/WillyShakes/flutter_auth)

First you need to create a instagram developer account on [instagram developer sign up page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/register/)

After that you need to create two darts file y the lib folder of your project. One of them is the instagram.dart file which is in the github project.

The other one is the constants.dart file, this should contain your APP_ID and APP_SECRET.

In the Module folder there's a Login folder which contains the actual login view (login_view.dart) and the LoginPresenter class (login_presenter.dart) which performs the actual login action in the method

> perform_login()

Here's the code

```
void perform_login() {
  assert(_view != null);
  // calls the getToken method of the Instagram class (instagram.dart)
  insta.getToken(constants.APP_ID,
    constants.APP_SECRET).then((token)
    {
      if (token != null) {
        _view.onLoginScuccess(token);
      }
      else {
        _view.onLoginError('Error');
      }
    });
 }
```

Comment: I've tried using the github you gave me, but it shows an error. here is the error message, {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid scope: []"}